# How do I use RTMP with Beats Music?

Tags: beatsmusic

I'm having trouble using RTMP with the Beats Music playback API. What library should I use to get playback working?

Answer (score 2):

You can now use the Beats Audio Manager to get playback in the browser. Check out the new *Web Playback Library* section of the docs:
https://developer.beatsmusic.com/docs

Comment: This is the recommended and supported method of desktop browser playback. Please do not delete this post.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people have been asking this question. RTMP was developed by Macromedia back in the day for streaming audio between a flash player and a server. I've found soundmanager2 to be pretty straight forward for streaming audio from a rtmp server. Here's a simple example using the Beats Music client auth running on a local node server:

https://github.com/jkyau/beatsmusic-node-rtmp/blob/master/node-example/views/index.html